# How can I add query string to NavLink?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to navigate to /home?onsite=1 using Navlink (React Router). How can I do this using NavLink?

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? You should add your attempt(s) to the question as a [mcve].

Comment: @ChrisHansen You can simply pass it. Please add some code, so that we can understand why its not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no special prop included in [`<NavLink />`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link) to apply a queryString.

---

You could just append it to the `to` prop:

```
return (
    <NavLink
        to={'/home/?onsite=1'}
        className={'very-nice-link'}
    >
        {'Navigate to Home'}
    </NavLink>
);
```

---

On the other hand, if you're able to use [`useNavigate()`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate) hook, you can provide a `search`:

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate({
    pathname: '/home',
    search: 'onsite=1'
})
```